# Google Map API v3 different setTrackColour for each different xml file?

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know what wrong with my coding?
I'm trying to make different color for each different XML file.
In the coding that I attached, as you can see if canal is 002 and their route will change their color to **RED**.

```js
parser.setTrackColour("#ff0000");     // Set the track line colour
```

For the other if canal is 003 their route will change their color to **BLACK**.

```js
parser.setTrackColour("#000000");     // Set the track line colour
```

This is my example full coding for your reference.

```js
if(canal == "002"){
    function loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, filename) {
        $.ajax({url: filename,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                var parser = new GPXParser(data, map);
                parser.setTrackColour("#ff0000");     // Set the track line colour
                parser.setTrackWidth(5);          // Set the track line width
                parser.setMinTrackPointDelta(0.001);      // Set the minimum distance between track points
                parser.centerAndZoom(data);
                parser.addTrackpointsToMap();         // Add the trackpoints
                parser.addWaypointsToMap();           // Add the waypoints

            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "routeXML/a.xml");
    });
}else
if(canal == "003"){
    function loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, filename) {
        $.ajax({url: filename,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                var parser = new GPXParser(data, map);
                parser.setTrackColour("#000000");     // Set the track line colour
                parser.setTrackWidth(5);          // Set the track line width
                parser.setMinTrackPointDelta(0.001);      // Set the minimum distance between track points
                parser.centerAndZoom(data);
                parser.addTrackpointsToMap();         // Add the trackpoints
                parser.addWaypointsToMap();           // Add the waypoints
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "routeXML/b.xml");
    });
}
```

Can someone please explain why I can't get what it should be?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: your code works fine for me, but when you want it for canal 003 you must add a branch for canal 003 (currently there are only branches for 002 and 004)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Sorry I'm wrong insert the code. Yea, It's actually 003. I edited it!